# Différence "gestionnaire de fortune" et "gérant de fortune"

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot

De langue maternelle française, j'ai souvent entendu, notamment durant mon expérience professionnelle dans le milieu bancaire, les deux expressions **gestionnaire de fortune** et **gérant de fortune**. Je n'ai pas pu trouver si l'une des expressions est plus correcte que l'autre pour désigner quelqu'un qui s'occupe de la gestion de la fortune d'un client, s'il y a une différence de sens (il ne me semble que non), ou si les deux expressions sont interchangeables ?

J'ai seulement l'impression que les banquiers privés utilisent plus volontiers *gérant de fortune*, peut-être que ça sonne simplement plus spécial. Je serais très heureux si quelqu'un pouvait donner quelques éclaircissements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il peut y avoir une connotation juridique, de pouvoir délégué :

> *Gérant* : Personne qui gère pour le compte d'autrui, *assume* une gérance, synonyme principal *administrateur* mais aussi plusieurs
>   autres dont *gestionnaire*.
>
> *Gestionnaire* : Qui concerne la gestion d'une affaire, ou qui en est chargé, un seul synonyme : *gérant*.
>
> (Le petit Robert)

On utilisera l'un ou l'autre selon que l'on délègue toutes les décisions à une personne (qui devient *le gérant*) et que l'on contrôle selon des procédures pré-établies, ou que l'on se sert des services d'un *gestionnaire* (qui peut aussi être un outil informatique) pour traiter la partie technique de l'affaire tout en restant décisionnaire sur les points importants.

Ne serait-ce que par le nombre de synonymes, l'activité *gestionnaire* est un sous-ensemble de l'activité *gérance*.

Comment: Au delà du sens réel des deux mots, l'usage semble un peu différent : on entend "gestionnaire de fortune" et "gérant d'un commerce" mais pas l'inverse. On peut dire de quelqu'un que c'est un *gestionnaire* tout court, mais s'il est gérant, il sera toujours *gérant* de quelque chose.